# HTML - Sequence Table

Tags: php, html, html-table

Im having some trouble making a sequence table. How do I make this in HTML?

`| Type 1       | Type 2      | Type 3       |`
`| T1a          | T1a_T2a     | T1a_T2a_T3a  |`
`|              |             | T1a_T2a_T3b  |`
`|              |             | T1a_T2a_T3c  |`
`|              | T1a_T2b     | T1a_T2b_T3a  |`
`|              |             | T1a_T2b_T3b  |`
`|              |             | T1a_T2b_T3c  |`

and so on.

Basically every type 1 has one or more type 2 and every type 2 has one or more type 3.

This happens inside a while loop.

This the pseudo-code which generates the table (real code is written in PHP):

```
while {
  <tr>  
     <td>
         ...print all Type 1 here...
     </td>  
     <td>  
       while {  
        .... print type 2 here ....
      </td>  
      <td> 
         while {  
         .... print type 3 here ...
         }  
       }  
      </td>
  <tr>  
}
```

Do you guys happen to know if this can be done and if so, how?

Thanks

**Edited: I used php to create the while loop and fetch data from the database**

Comment: I guess you want to take a look at the `rowspan` of `td` elements.

Comment: @gibberish I don't think he's asking for that.. I think he's just asking how to construct a table with three columns.. `<tr><!-- <td></td> for each column --></tr>`-like.

Comment: Please, be more clearer....For example: From where you get your data types?

Comment: @AlgernopK. - Thinking is not knowing what the OP really want

Comment: @aldanux Just hypothesising, like the other comments. Wasn't tagged php before =)

Comment: guys..i used php's while loop and fetch data form the database

Comment: Improved formatting and grammar. Made some clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

First, you might prefer the `th` element for the headers (Type1, -2, -3).

To actually create the table, I propose this (more or less pseudo-code, but I think you get the idea...):

```
foreach($type1)
{
    $td1 = $type1.value;
    foreach($type1.getChildren() as $type2)
    {
        $td2 = $type2.value;
        foreach($type2.getChildren() as $type3)
        {
            echo '<tr><td>$td1</td><td>$td2</td><td>$type3.value</td></tr>';
            $t1 = $t2 = '';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the answers and comments... i finally made a solution... basically...the way my code works is:

```
column | type 1 | Type 2 | Type 3      |     
   print: T1a -> T1a_T2a -> T1a_T2a_T3a  
                         -> T1a_T2a_T3b  
                         -> T1a_T2a_T3a
```

then it go should go back to column type 2 and print all T3 for T2b:

```
column | type 1 | Type 2 | Type 3      |     
   print: T1a -> T1a_T2a -> T1a_T2a_T3a  
                         -> T1a_T2a_T3b  
                         -> T1a_T2a_T3a         1st row
                 T1a_T2b -> T1a_T2b_T3a 
                            T1a_T2b_T3b  
                            T1a_T2b_T3c  
----------------------------------------
```

however i cant see to make it go back to column type 2 and this is what happens:

```
column | type 1 | Type 2 | Type 3      |   column 4   |
print: T1a -> T1a_T2a -> T1a_T2a_T3a  
                         -> T1a_T2a_T3b  -> T1a_T2b_T3a
                         -> T1a_T2a_T3a  -> T1a_T2b_T3b    1st row
                            T1a_T2b      -> T1a_T2b_T3c  
--------------------------------------------------------
```

since it cant go back to the previous , it just creates a new column (column 4)

so what I did is after fetching all type 3 for a specific type 2, I add a new row and leaving column type 1 empty then print type 2 and all its type 3.

```
column | type 1 | Type 2 | Type 3      |     
   print: T1a -> T1a_T2a -> T1a_T2a_T3a  
                         -> T1a_T2a_T3b       1st row
                         -> T1a_T2a_T3a 
-----------------------------------------        
        (empty)  T1a_T2b -> T1a_T2b_T3a       2nd row
                            T1a_T2b_T3b  
                            T1a_T2b_T3c  
----------------------------------------
```

I hope you guys get it..Sorry Im not really good at explaining :)

here is what it looks like:

```
while {  
 <tr>
   <td>
     print here type 1
   </td>  
 while {  
   <td>  
     print here type 2
   </td>
   <td>
     while {  
          print here type 3
     }
   </td>
 </tr>   -------- this breaks the current row  
 <tr>    -------- adds new row
   <td>  
         (empty)  
   </td>
 }
 </tr>   --------- breaks the row if all type 2 for type 1 is done.
}
```